# How do I pass the Gitlab {CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} variable to powershell script

Tags: powershell, gitlab

I have created a script section in Gitlab-CI.yaml file. The format is given below.

```
script:
   - powershell -File script.ps1 folderpath="$env:${CI_PROJECT_DIR}" CommitID="$env:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"
```

and these variables are calling in my PowerShell script as follows. The script is given below.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem $folderpath
foreach($eachFile in $Files)
{
    if($eachFile.Name.Contains("myapp"))
    {
        Rename-Item -Path $eachFile.FullName -NewName "myapp-$CommitID.zip" -Force
    }
}
```

This script is using for changing the name of a zip file. After execting this through gitlab I am getting error like this.

```
 Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name 
 character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.
```

Is it the right format to pass the GitLab env variable to PowerShell script? Can you please suggest some inputs on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Assuming that `${CI_PROJECT_DIR}` is the *value* of GitLab's `CI_PROJECT_DIR` (environment) variable, you can use it as-is in your command line - no need for the `$env:` indirection, which (a) requires the *name* of an environment variable and (b) wouldn't work anyway with PowerShell's `-File` CLI parameter.
- Assuming your target script uses regular PowerShell parameter declarations (e.g., `param($FolderPath, $CommitId)`, case doesn't matter), you must pass the values using
  `-<param> <value>` or `-<param>:<value>` syntax.

To put it all together:

```
script:
   - powershell -File script.ps1 -FolderPath "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}" -CommitID="${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"
```

---

The alternative is not to use *parameters* at all, and instead directly access the environment variables *from inside your script*, using PowerShell's `$env:<var_name>` notation:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem $env:CI_PROJECT_DIR
foreach($eachFile in $Files)
{
  if($eachFile.Name.Contains("myapp"))
  {
     Rename-Item $eachFile.FullName -NewName "myapp-$env:CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA.zip" -Force
  }
}
```